# php add required files correctly

Tags: php

i have following folder structure.

[image]

**config.php**

```
<?php
class config {
    const server = "localhost";
}
```

**conn.php**

```
<?php
 require_once './config.php';
```

**firstExample.php**

```
<?php

require_once './db/conn.php';
```

when i run `conn.php` there is no errors.but if i run `firstExample.php` i got following error

```
Warning: require_once(./config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\testX\db\conn.php on line 2
```

i do some tests and able to fix the error by changing `conn.php` to

```
require_once './db/config.php';
```

my question is i need to add `conn.php` from lot of folders,sub folders.so changing like above doesn't work.for example if i run `conn.php` after above change then again i'm getting same error.

what i want to know is correct way of adding files.so when i add `conn.php` to any file `config.php` should be included.

Comment: Your answer is here, together with explanations : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Directory structure

you do not need to put "./"

Try:

```
 require_once 'config.php';
```

Or you can define path in CONSTANT and use it.

Comment: i thought  './config.php' and 'config.php' both are same.but it seems that avoiding ./ fix the problem.let me test more

Answer (score 1):

You can use [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable in PHP : `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`

So your `conn.php` will change to:

```
<?php
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/db/config.php';
```

when `testX` is your root folder.

Comment: There is a general troubleshooting guide here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. This is path of your document root `C:\wamp\www`, so including despite where the file is the link to required file is the same `require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/testX/db/config.php';`

But due to server settings it not always shows to this directory. For more bullet proof method you should define path in your `index.php` or other file, that is in root directory & later use that define, eg: 
`define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__) );`
and later just use:
`require_once BASE_PATH.'/testX/db/config.php;`

Comment: There is a general checklist of solutions here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the magic constant `__DIR__` which will build absolute path based on the directory containing the file being executed/included:

**conn.php**

```
require_once __DIR__.'/config.php';
```

**firstExample.php**

```
require_once __DIR__.'/db/conn.php';
```

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php